# Notice: Undefined index: valorDireita in C:\xampp\htdocs\Anexus\arvoreBinariaAnexus\class\arvore.class.php on line 47

Tags: php

Meu código cria uma árvore binária que é criada com um array de itens randômicos e os monta enviando para direita ou esquerda do número anterior conforme regra geral da criação da árvore.

Na execução tenho recebido dois erros e não consigo saber o que está havendo. Os erros são:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: valorDireita in C:\xampp\htdocs\Anexus\arvoreBinariaAnexus\class\arvore.class.php on line 47
```

e

```
Notice:  Undefined index: valorEsquerda in C:\xampp\htdocs\Anexus\arvoreBinariaAnexus\class\arvore.class.php on line 31
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Arvore Binária</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Árvore Binaria</h1>
    <h2>Random de 10 numeros, de 1 a 100</h2>
    <h2>Sistema de Indicação</h2>
    <?php

        include 'class/arvore.class.php';
        include 'class/no.class.php';

        $no1 = New No();
        $arvore = New Arvore();

      //  echo '<pre>';

        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= 10) 
        {
            $i++;
            $arvore->inserir($no1, random_int(1, 100));
        }

    ?>

    <h2>Totais</h2>
    <?php

        echo "<br>Quantidade da Esquerda = " . $valorEsquerda;
        echo "<br>Total de pontos da Esquerda = " . $valorEsquerda * 200;

        echo "<br><br><br>";

        echo "<br>quantidade da Direita = ".$valorDireita -= 1;
        echo "<br>Total de pontos da Direita = " .$valorDireita * 100;

        echo "<br><br><br>";

    ?>
<!--
    <h2>Estrutura do nó</h2>
    <?php

        print_r($no1);

    ?>
-->
</body>

</html>
```

no.class.php

```
<?php
class No {

    public $raiz;
    public $esquerda;
    public $direita;
    public $valor;

    public function __construct($valor = ' ') {
        if ( $valor != ' ' && !is_null($valor) ) {
            $this->valor = $valor;
        }
    }
}
```

arvore.class.php

```
<?php

class Arvore {

    public $valorDireita;
    public $valorEsquerda;

    public function inserir($node, $valor) {

        $i = 0;
        if ($i = 0) {

            echo "Inserindo Raiz" . $valor . "<br>";
            $node->raiz = new No($valor);
            $i++;

        // Verifica se a árvore já foi criada
        } elseif ($node != NULL) {

            // Verifica se o valor a ser inserido é menor que o do nodo corrente da árvore, se sim vai para a subarvore esquerda
            if ($valor < $node->valor) {

                // Se tiver elemento no modo esquerdo continua a busca
                if ($node->esquerda != NULL) {

                    $this->inserir($node->esquerda, $valor);

                } else {

                    // se nodo esquerdo vazio insere o novo modo aqui e adiciona 200
                    echo "Inserindo " . $valor . " a esquerda de " . $node->valor . "<br>";
                    $node->esquerda = new No($valor);
                    $GLOBALS["valorEsquerda"] += 1;

                }    
            // Verifica se o valor a ser inserido é maior que o nodo corrente da árvore, se sim vai para subarvore direta
            } elseif ($valor > $node->valor) {

                // Se tiver elemento no modo direto continua a busca
                if ($node->direita != NULL) {

                    $this->inserir($node->direita, $valor);

                } else {

                    // Se nodo direito vazio insere o novo modo aqui e adiciona 100 
                    echo "Inserindo " . $valor . " a direita de " . $node->valor . "<br>";
                    $node->direita = new No($valor);
                    $GLOBALS["valorDireita"] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Executei seu código aqui no computador, e não entendi muito bem qual o problema ele está rodando certinho, o erro em questão se dá porque a variavel $node->valor que você usa para exibir no loop começa vazia, repare que na imagem a primeira linha tem "Inserindo 81 a direita de ", ou seja você inseriu 81 e a esquerda dele não tinha nada na variável $node->valor então logo em seguida ele exibe um erro, é a mesma coisa na primeira inserção a direita, logo a baixo no segundo erro, você inseriu porém a esquerda não tinha nada na variável $node->valor então o PHP exibe esse erro, mas isso não quer dizer que seu código está errado.

Você pode solucionar isso adaptando a sua regra de negócio lá no arvore.class.php uma condicional IF que caso exibe uma mensagem diferente na primeira vez que o $node->valor for vazio, algo como..

`if ($node->valor = null) {
echo "Inserindo " .$valor. "
";
}`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grato pelo retorno. Funcionou a tua correção.